# What is Replacement for HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(builder.build().toString());

Tags: java, solr

What is Replacement for

```
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(builder.build().toString());
```

Comment: what's wrong with above?

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution:

SolrClient solrServer = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrLocation).build();

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrServer.html#HttpSolrServer(java.lang.String)) says:

> Deprecated.   Use HttpSolrClient
>
> @Deprecated public class HttpSolrServer extends HttpSolrClient

```
HttpSolrClient solrServer = new HttpSolrClient (builder.build().toString());
```

Comment: @KarthickVijay  `SolrClient solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();`

Comment: @KarthickVijay `HttpSolrServer` is deprecated, you should use `HttpSolrClient` instead

Comment: the intention here is... I dont want to use any deprecated classes in my program..

Comment: @KarthickVijay It is ok. See the code that i suggest, what is there deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Use below for Solrj 9.x

```
SolrClient client = new Http2SolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/Collection1").build()
```